# How to properly nest loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

i’m having a hard time figuring out why when i run my code it skips all of the if statements and just puts invalid. i have a 2d array with values which represents a movie theater and i’m supposed to be selling tickets, the user is supposed to enter a sum of money that determines where they’ll sit, which is the most expensive seat they could afford from the selection. the seat that the person gets should change from whatever number to 0. at the end i need to print the new array with the zeroes.

this what i've tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean done = false;
        //initial seating chart
    int [] [] table = 
        {
            {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
            {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
            {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
            {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
            {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
            {30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30},
            {40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40},
            {40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40},
            {50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50},
        };
    while (!done) {
        int row; int col;
        //search seating chart
        for (row=0; row<9; row++) {
            for (col=0; col<8; col++) {
                System.out.printf("Enter maximum amount that you would like to spend on the tickets: ");
                int amount = in.nextInt();
                if (table[row][col]==10 && 10<=amount && amount<20) {
                table[row][col]=0;
                    System.out.printf("Ticket located at Row %d Seat %d purchased for 10\n", row+1, col+1);
                    System.out.print("Would you like to purchase additional tickets? (Y/N) " + in.next());
                    if (in.hasNext("y")) {
                        done = false;
                    }
                    else {done = true;
                    }
                    }
                else if (table[row][col]==20 && 20<=amount && amount<30) {
                    table[row][col]=0;
                    System.out.printf("Ticket located at Row %d Seat %d purchased for 20\n", row+1, col+1);
                    System.out.print("Would you like to purchase additional tickets? (Y/N) " + in.next());
                    if (in.hasNext("y")) {
                        done = false;
                    }
                    else {done = true;
                    }
                    }
                else if (table[row][col]==30 && 30<=amount && amount<40) {
                    table[row][col]=0;
                    System.out.printf("Ticket located at Row %d Seat %d purchased for 30\n", row+1, col+1);
                    System.out.print("Would you like to purchase additional tickets? (Y/N) " + in.next());
                    if (in.hasNext("y")) {
                        done = false;
                    }
                    else {done = true;
                    }
                    }
                else if (table[row][col]==40 && 40<=amount && amount<50) {
                    table[row][col]=0;
                    System.out.printf("Ticket located at Row %d Seat %d purchased for 40\n", row+1, col+1);
                    System.out.print("Would you like to purchase additional tickets? (Y/N) " + in.next());
                    if (in.hasNext("y")) {
                        done = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        done = true;
                    }
                    }
                else if (table[row][col]==50 && 50<=amount) {
                    table[row][col]=0;
                    System.out.printf("Ticket located at Row %d Seat %d purchased for 50\n", row+1, col+1);
                    System.out.print("Would you like to purchase additional tickets? (Y/N) " + in.next());
                    if (in.hasNext("y")) {
                        done = false;
                    }
                    else {done = true;
                    }
                    }
                else {System.out.print("invalid");}
        }}}
        //final seating chart
        System.out.print(table);
}
}
```

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two different programming languages.

Comment: thanks. could you help me despite that?

Comment: your looping through the 2 for loops is unnecesary, the customer has to be extremly lucky to get a seat where the row and col are at the price range where he wants to sit, as in at the start if i choose 45 -> then i get into the 3rd else if but at that point table[0][0] is at 10 so it fails.. im cooking up a code example which would explain better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample to understand better, im covering one case here as the rest are considerably the same

```
//private variable here so we could find and book seat through method findAvailableSeat()
private static int[][] table = { { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }, { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 },
        { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }, { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 },
        { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 }, { 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30 },
        { 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40 }, { 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40 },
        { 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50 }, };
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;
    // initial seating chart

    while (!done) {
        int row;
        int col;
        // search seating chart
        System.out.printf("Enter maximum amount that you would like to spend on the tickets: ");
        int amount = in.nextInt();
        if (10 <= amount && amount < 20) {
            String location = findAvailableSeat(10);//store the indexes in a variable to show the user later
            if(location != null) {
                String[] locationList = location.split(",");
                row = Integer.parseInt(locationList[0]);
                col = Integer.parseInt(locationList[1]);
                System.out.printf("Ticket located at Row %d Seat %d purchased for 10\n", row + 1, col + 1);
                System.out.print("Would you like to purchase additional tickets? (Y/N) ");
                String resp = in.next(); //this statement is needed as sometimes with in.next() rushes to user input without printing text
                if (resp.equals("Y")) {
                    done = false;
                } else {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            else 
                System.out.printf("No available seat found\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and in the method we have

```
private static String findAvailableSeat(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int row=0; row<9; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<8; col++) {
            if(table[row][col]==i) {
                //find the seat location, set location to 0 and then return indices to show in user result
                table[row][col] = 0;
                return row + "," + col;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```